# Photoshop script to add filename as text and adjust size

Tags: javascript, css, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a Photoshop script to add the filename as a text layer (without the extension) and then reposition it and change the font size. It all works perfectly except for the font size - it keeps defaulting to 50px.

```
var docRef = activeDocument;

// Now create a text layer at the front
var myLayerRef = docRef.artLayers.add();
myLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
myLayerRef.name = "Filename";


var myTextRef = myLayerRef.textItem;

// strip the extension off
var fileNameNoExtension = docRef.name;
fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.split( "." );
if ( fileNameNoExtension.length > 1 ) {
    fileNameNoExtension.length--;
}
fileNameNoExtension = fileNameNoExtension.join(".");
myTextRef.contents = fileNameNoExtension.substring(0);


// off set the text to be in the middle
myTextRef.position = new Array( "279", "641");
myTextRef.size = new UnitValue(20, 'px');
```

If I remove the last line, the text defaults to 12px. I have also tried replacing the last line with the following code:

```
myTextRef.size = new UnitValue("20", "px");
myTextRef.size = "20";
myTextRef.size = 20;
myTextRef.size = "20 px";
myTextRef.size = 20px;
```

Comment: Welcome to OS. What have you got the ruler units & type units set to?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I have both of them set to pixels and I've been using other scripts to resize and position layers and they all work fine. If I remove the last line of code, the text shows up as 12px.

Comment: `myTextRef.size = 90;` or `myTextRef.size = 6;` works fine in CS2 - You shouldn't need to use a pixel value, just an integer

Comment: Oh wow that actually worked! I figured out if I set it to around 8 that's the size I need. I can't believe I missed that so completely.